# Obstructions to non-separable geometry

Tags: general-topology, geometry, logic, set-theory

I'm curious about generalizations of Euclidean geometry to non-separable spaces.

Specifically, my question would be: Which are the obvious obstructions to having a model of (some considerable fraction) of Hilbert axioms, where the base topological space is non-separable?

Even more particularly,

> what would a “Suslin plane” look like?

With this term I mean the cartesian product of two [Suslin lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem).
This was my original question, but then I realized that perhaps non-separability would be a prior obstacle.

I was playing a little bit with the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)), trying to define a *wide plane*. It's kinda evident that an obvious, “affine” approach (that is, trying to define a line as something like $ax + by =0 $) will not work here.

Comment: I dk what you might do geometrically with SxS if S is a Suslin line. You can't define vector sums in any obvious way, as S is not the order of any ordered topological group.  An ordered topological group  has equal density and cellularity.

Comment: @user254665 Thanks; it seems your remark handles the Suslin case, at least taking an “affine” approach. I really don't know if some synthetic geometric can be done in spite of that. What about the general question, do you think separability is necessary?

Comment: I dk. I'd have to look up Hilbert's treatment again. Something else,which I know little of,which might be appropriate  (maybe) is something  by John von Neumann that he called continuous geometry.